# Filter JSONObject in JSONArray Android

Tags: android, json, arraylist, arrays

How I filter this JSONArray that the JSONObject "name" contain "abcd"

```
{
    "items":[{
            "id":"082111",
            "name":"abcd efgh"
        }, {
            "id":"082112",
            "name":"abcd klmn"
        }, {
            "id":"082113",
            "name":"klmn efgh"
        }, {
            "id":"082114",
            "name":"abcd efgh"
        }, {
            "id":"082115",
            "name":"efgh oprs"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the result is must be

```
{
    "items":[{
            "id":"082111",
            "name":"abcd efgh"
        }, {
            "id":"082112",
            "name":"abcd klmn"
        }, {
            "id":"082114",
            "name":"abcd efgh"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can get the result like that?
Should I convert the JSONArray to ArrayList, and filter when have converted to ArrayList, and convert again to JSONArray?
If yes, how i convert the JSONArray to ArrayList and filter it? And conver again to JSONArray?
Please give me samples code.

Comment: There are number of Tutorial to Implement such a thing. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you'll get that which ever you required that is which are starting with the letters abcd like as you said.

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jData = json.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jData.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = jData.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((jo.getString("name")).startsWith("abcd", 0)) {

                    Log.i("Name is ", jo.getString("name"));

                }

            }
```

Comment: Will there be any functions similar to "filteredArrayUsingPredicate" in iOS or without using the for-loop? If the json array contains 10'000 objects, will the for-loop method too slow ??

Comment: I think in iOS also you can retrieve with the startsWith() you can check the methods in iOS . i don't have idea abt iOS.

Comment: Sorry for mis-presenting. I mean in Android, if i use the "for-loop" approach to do the filtering with many JSONObject, will it drag the android device performance? If yes, then do you have better suggestions? Many thanks for your response.

Comment: if you want to achieve best performance you use either gson or Jakson parsing for your needs.For more information on efficient ways of parsing json data [refer this](https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android)